# Creating jks keystore with openssl

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, jks

does anybody know how to create a jks keystore?
I've been looking for ages how to create a jsk keystore for my sava program but every website gives different tutorials.

thx for help 
Steff

Comment: There are many questions related to this on stackoverflow and many tutorials as well. Please follow tutorials from some good websites.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12452_01/resa/pdf/141/html/merch_sg/apps-chapter%207.htm) for creating the SLL certificate using keytool.
I think it may be helpful to you.